# How to make Firefox and Chromium play video in tab instead of downloading?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, browser

I  am wondering is there special plugin needed? For chrome it is fine as the video immediately play inside the tab (streaming) instead of asking me to download it.

Comment: Browsers usually need video player plugins to stream different types of video files instead of downloading them. In Firefox, you can check if a video plugin is installed by clicking on File -> Addons and selecting "Plugins" on the left. VLC for example automatically installs one of them.

Comment: Hi stex thanks for your tips! I installed VLC and it seems to work fine. I am wondering is there any alternative to VLC that could also install plugin in firefox/chrome? Coz I am looking for one that can actually cache the file (i.e. when you move the slider back to already streamed content, you don't have to stream again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try Windows Media Player plugin or QuickTime plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox can play WebM and Ogg Theora Vorbis files without any plugins.

Here's a Firefox Support article on Windows Media Player Plugin: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/play-windows-media-files-in-firefox

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out that in Chrome if you "open link in new tab" (right-click) it will just stream it instead of download.

NOTE: I do have Windows 10 and VLC installed (with the plugins)